# jQuery how to select td with rowspan attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, html-table

The code below can get the html table tds with attribute 'rowspan',

```
 $elem.find('td').filter('[rowspan]')
```

but how can I get the tds who's 'rowspan' is more than 1,like:

```
$elem.find('td').filter('[rowspan > 1]')
```

Comment: anyone know how to do this with Vanilla?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply a `function` to your `filter` and return elements whose `rowSpan` is greater than `1`:

```
$.elem.find('td').filter(function() {
  return this.rowSpan > 1;
});
```

*Note that there's no need to wrap `attr()` or re-wrap `this` (as `$(this)`) as `rowSpan` is a native element property (which is conveniently already a numeric type, so no number conversion is needed).*

### Example

```js
$('td').filter(function() {
    return this.rowSpan > 1;
}).css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>No rowspan</td>
      <td rowspan=1>Rowspan 1</td>
      <td rowspan=2>Rowspan 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :-

```
$elem.find('td').filter(function(){
   return (parseInt($(this).attr('rowspan'),10) > 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use : `parseInt($(this).attr('rowspan'),10) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate in each `td` element and check if attribute `rowspan` is > 1. In my example I use css class to represent if a td has rowspan > 1 adding to this element class `pass` or `fail` accordingly.

```js
$("table tbody tr td[rowspan]").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass(parseInt($(this).attr("rowspan"), 10) > 1 ? "pass" : "fail");
});
```

```css
.pass {
  background: green;
}
.fail {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan='2'>2</td>
      <td rowspan='3'>3</td>
      <td>no rowspan</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan='2'>2</td>
      <td rowspan='3'>3</td>
      <td>no rowspan</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan='2'>2</td>
      <td rowspan='3'>3</td>
      <td>no rowspan</td>
      <td rowspan='1'>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the tds who's 'rowspan' is more than 1, you may try the following:

```
var allTdsWithMoreThanOneRowspan = $elem.find('td[rowspan]').filter(function () {   
   return ($(this).attr('rowspan') > 1);
})
```